# Scoping in Rails with a has_one relationship and an OR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm having trouble setting up a scope that will check a value on a `has_one` relationship. I have a `Document` model. Each Document `has_one` `Document::Response`, and `Document::Response` has a `status` field (I generated the `Document::Response` model with `rails g model documents/response`, which made things a bit more confusing than I'd anticipated. The strong parameters method references it as `:document_responses` for example. Not sure if it's relevant though. )

```
scope :rejected, -> { joins(:response).where(status: 'rejected') }
```

I'll also need to check for something else once I get that working:

```
scope :rejected, -> { joins(:response).where(status: 'rejected').or(status: 'owed' }
```

But I can't seem to get the syntax right on this.

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column documents.status does not exist
LINE 1: ...ts"."id" WHERE "documents"."mortgage_id" = $1 AND "documents...
                                                             ^
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "documents" INNER JOIN "document_responses" ON 
"document_responses"."document_id" = "documents"."id" WHERE 
"documents"."mortgage_id" = $1 AND "documents"."status" = $2
```

Routes:

```
  resources :mortgages, shallow: true do
    resources :documents do
      collection do
        post :create_templates
      end
    end
    member do
      post :archive
    end
  end

 resources :responses, controller: 'document/responses' do
    member do
      post :accept
      post :reject
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you please tell us what you observe going wrong? i there an error message? if so - edit your question and add it... or whatever else you have seen/tried.

Comment: Rails version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is required to explicitly tell AR to use `status` column from `responses` table instead of `documents`:

```
scope :rejected, -> {
  joins(:response).where(responses: { status: 'rejected' })
}

scope :processed, -> {
  joins(:response).where(responses: { status: ['rejected', 'owed'] })
}
```